# Remove all comments from VB.NET source code file

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, comments

Is there a macro in the Visual Studio editor to remove all comments from a VB.NET source file?

Comment: Just curious. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have refactored a module I've been working on - whereby I commented out X lines of code and then rewrote that code above the comment. Now that my code passes all tests I want to remove the commented out code and add appropriate comments to the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using menu Edit -> Find and Replace -> Quick Replace with Regular expressions

Find what: `^{.+}'.+$`

Replace with: `\1`

will replace

```
text ' comment
```

to

```
text
```

Comment: @abatishchev - It removes the entire line!  Which I obviously do not want. e.g. `Dim path As String ' temporary file path` - would remove the entire line.

Comment: @roygbiv: My first variant will remove the whole line. The current one - will not

Comment: Highlights on Find next? Right. The whole line matches. And it will be replaced with the part of it - from the beginning up to the comment sign

Comment: Just tried out your regex. Works great. There is a problem though, if the commented line is like `'' This is a comment` then it only deletes `' This is a comment`. There is still a `'` left in the line.

Comment: @Soham: Maybe `[']+` will work, should mean `'` 1 times or more

Comment: @Soham: Please ask another question, and give me a link. Very interesting to myself to get an answer. I'm not very good with RegEx

Comment: I have created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511510/visual-studio-regex-to-find-and-replace-all-comments-in-vb-net-code). Please check.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT*

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/579000-utility-remove-comments-vb-net-files

has some options.

such as

- write a VB.NET program to do it?
  should be easy: any line with a single quote as the first character
  should be removed. and everything AFTER a single quote (even if it's
  not the first character), provided the quote is not between a pair of
  double quotes.
  and the files you send to this program are any *.vb files.
- search and replace with a regular expression would
  probably be quickest.

Comment: Interesting suggestions.  I knew it would come down to this.  Thought there was an easier point and click way.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `^{(([^"']*"[^"]*"[^"'])#|[^"']*)}'.*$`

Replace with `\1`
will also work for stuff like this (SQL):

```
   cs = "INSERT INTO db (time, t1, t2) VALUES ('" & Time.ToString & "', NULL, '" & t2 & "')" ' COMMENT
```