# Exclude comments regex not working in Visual Studio 2017 Find

Tags: regex, comments

As per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) document there is change in regex methodology from vs 2010 to vs 2012.

Using below Regex I am able to exclude all the comment in VS2010 for all cases

```
^~(:b*').*your_search_term.
```

But when we try below  regex (After changes suggested in the doument) i am able to Exclude comments from Visual Studio Find's search results but only for some cases.

```
^(?![ \t]*[']).*your_search_term.    
^(?!(\s*')).*your_search_term.
^(?!(?([^\r\n])\s)*').*your_search_term.
```

above Regex fails for cases when comments are in the same line as code.

```
ex: Try  ' On Error GoTo test_EH
```

Is there any way to Find by excluding all the comments using  Visual Studio 2017 Find?

Edited:
Cases we have checked regex For:

```
1. when comments are in the same line as code.
   ex: Try  ' On Error GoTo test_EH

2. When only Comment present in a line
   ex: 'On Error GoTo test_EH

3. When there are words within ' ' in code
   ex: Dim str1 As String = " 'test_EH' "
```

Edited:

modifying the regex mentioned in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568349/16686946) , I could able to detect all the comments in the project which include test word.

```
(?mn)^(?<line>[^\r\n"']*(("[^"]*")[^\r\n"]*)*)(')[^\r\n]*test[^\r\n]*
```

but negating that regex to exclude comment will also exclude the below case:

```
Dim test a string 'this is test example
```

How to modify this regex to exclude comments properly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that old syntax BUT based on your requirement a new regex can be built such as:

```
(?:^\s*|\s+)'(?!.*').*test_EH
```

Basically, this will match any:

- line starting with `'`
- line ending with a text proceeded by a single `'`

In both cases, only 1 `'` is allowed AND the text `test_EH` must be found as well

**DEMO:**

https://regex101.com/r/wj7M9t/1

Please comment with more details/examples to fine-tune it if needed

Answer (score -2):

I have combined and created the regex for vb.net language which works for all above mentioned cases in VS2017.

Regex:

```
(^(?!.*').*mexico)|((\"(.*(mexico).*)+?\")|('(.*(mexico).*)+?'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).