# Visual Studio: Remove comments from VB.NET source code file

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to remove all the comments from my VB.NET project (in VS 2010) using regex through Find & Replace. I have already referred to these 2 questions:

- [Visual Studio regex to remove all comments and blank lines in VB.NET code using a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511510/visual-studio-regex-to-remove-all-comments-and-blank-lines-in-vb-net-code-using)
- [Remove all comments from VB.NET source code file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563202/remove-all-comments-from-vb-net-source-code-file)

But, the problem is my project has numerous lines of code which looks like this:

```
    Const SQLQuery As String = "Select Distinct * from [TableName] where Field='N' and Field1=@Field order by Field"
```

By using the solutions mentioned in the links, parts of the lines after ' (single quote) too gets eliminated, which shouldn't be happening.

Also, when I used the regex

```
(?mn)^(?<line>[^\r\n"R']*(("[^"]*"|(?!REM)R)[^\r\n"R']*)*)(REM|')[^\r\n]*
```

provided in an answer on link no 1, Visual Studio throws an error called "Argument is missing in the pattern". Now I am assuming the above mentioned regex needs to be executed through a macro or something and by passing some parameters, but I have no clue about it.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but VS2010 has a bastardized regex syntax, its not like pcre.

Comment: Consider a use of Roslyn to remove the comments. [Example in C#.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fff018eb-ae2d-49fc-a0e6-a466cc26b283/how-to-remove-all-comments-in-a-cs-textfile-with-roslyn?forum=roslyn)

Comment: @Jeremy not sure what you wanted to ask!

Comment: @sln Buddy I've no idea about regex, could you please help me out with this!